# Is it possible to draw a rectangle from inside a java class in processing?

Tags: java, processing

I want to have a java object that I would call object.draw() from inside the main draw() method so that every time the processing sketch draws it draws the java object.

Comment: This is a **processing** question. It's perfectly clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

You just need to pass the `PApplet` instance into the Java class, and then use that to do your drawing.

```
public class MyShape{
   PApplet papplet;

   public MyShape(PApplet papplet){
      this.papplet = papplet;
   }

   public void draw(){
      papplet.ellipse(50, 50, 25, 25);
   }
}
```

And then in your sketch, you would use the `this` keyword to pass the sketch into your object:

```
MyShape myShape;

void setup(){
   myShape = new myShape(this);
}

void draw(){
   myShape.draw();
}
```

More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/this.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help, immediately after posting this I thought of the same thing and forgot I asked the question.